# I am having trouble with firebase, I am trying to get a list but even though there are values, the list is not displayed in my recycleview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code for the firebase access and through several methods, it should be displayed in the below code.
So the problem is that even though I have values in my firebase realtime database I am unable to get them. The strange thing is that I have used the same way this code in another part of the application and there it works fine, just it only retrieves when I click on a TextView, so if someone would know how to call this upon opening the fragment that would be good to know as well!

```
@Override
public ArrayList<Chore> getChoresByFlatmate() {
    ArrayList<Chore> chores = new ArrayList<>();
    myref.child("flats").child(flatID).child("chores").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            chores.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (snapshot1.child("assignedto").getValue().equals(flatmateID)) {
                    chores.add(snapshot1.getValue(Chore.class));
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Log.e("Getting chores error", error.getDetails());
        }
    });
    return chores;
}
```

Where it should display it:
Adapter class:

```
public class OwnChoresAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OwnChoresAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Chore> chores;
private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

public OwnChoresAdapter() {
    homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel();
    chores = homeViewModel.getChoresByUser();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public OwnChoresAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleownchore, parent, false);
    return new OwnChoresAdapter.ViewHolder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OwnChoresAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.done.setOnClickListener(v -> homeViewModel.delete(chores.get(position).getChoreID()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return chores.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    TextView desc;
    Button done;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_nameown);
        desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_descown);
        done = itemView.findViewById(R.id.accept_taskown);
    }
}
```

}

Fagment where it should display:

```
RecyclerView latestCosts;
CostAdapter costAdapter;
RecyclerView ownchores;
OwnChoresAdapter ownChoresAdapter;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    latestCosts = root.findViewById(R.id.rvlatestexpenses);
    latestCosts.hasFixedSize();
    latestCosts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    costAdapter = new CostAdapter();
    latestCosts.setAdapter(costAdapter);

    ownchores = root.findViewById(R.id.rvowntasks);
    ownchores.hasFixedSize();
    ownchores.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    ownChoresAdapter = new OwnChoresAdapter();
    ownchores.setAdapter(ownChoresAdapter);

    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you're adding the updated data to the `chores` array that is shown in the view, the adapter will only update the UI when you inform it about the change in its data by calling `notifyDataSetChanged`.

So you'll want to call that at the end of `onDataChange`:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    chores.clear();
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
        if (snapshot1.child("assignedto").getValue().equals(flatmateID)) {
            chores.add(snapshot1.getValue(Chore.class));
        }
    }
    ownChoresAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //  add this to your code
}
```